# Criteria - Get projection property given the alias

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection

Say that we have a well formed criteria object with a projection list set as projection. Something like this :

```
   ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
   projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"), "alias1");
   projectionList.add(Projections.property("client_project.name"), "alias2");
   projectionList.add(Projections.property("project.name"), "alias3");
   projectionList.add(Projections.property("name"), "alias4");
   criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

In other parts of the code where only the criteria is in the scope, how i can manage to retrieve given an "alias", the correspondent projection? Is there any way or perhaps i am misunderstanding somethings.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Comment: I have searched thought the java docs, something suggest me that the projection <-> alias relation is not really bijective...